# How to scroll a UITableView when text field is selected

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a UITableView which is composed of custom cells. The cells are made of 5 text fields next to each other (sort of like a grid).

When I try to scroll and edit the cells at the bottom of the UITableView, I can't manage to get my cells properly positioned above the keyboard.

I have seen many answers talking about changing view sizes,etc... but none of them has worked nicely so far.

Could anybody clarify the "right" way to do this with a concrete code example?